# AngularJs modules LazyLoading

Tags: angularjs, lazy-loading

At work we use a global module/main-app

```
<html ng-app="mainApp" />
```

First of all, is it good or bad to use a global module?

Second, I don't want to load all dependencies in this global module so I want to use a lazy loader, but what do you think of this solution?

```
// Set my module as main module
$("#ng-app").attr("ng-app", "myModule");

// Load the global module and another directive
var app = angular.module('myModule', ["mainApp", "angucomplete"]);
```

I want to mention that I am using `AngularJS` with `CodeIgniter` so I'm loading the JS script in view rather than include it in module dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using lazy load because I use require.js... if you need, you can put at end of your js:

```
angular.bootstrap(document, ['mainApp']);
```

See this sample on: [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/solixi/3/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Thank you!
And you can change the global module anytime you want using angularjs instead of jquery , nice solution.